# How to populate "Recipients" in Circulation list?

Tags: 2010, list

I have created a workflow that adds an item to the Circulations list so that everyone in a (static, unchanging) group can "approve" the item.

I cannot  figure out what I need to put in the "Recipients" field in order to get this to populate correctly.  Everything I've tried results in the workflow leaving the "Recipients" field blank, and the circulation automatically is completed (probably because it had no recipients to show it to).

I've tried manually entering recipients for testing:
ABC>XYZ
DOMAIN\Abc.Xyz
Abc Xyz
"Abc Xyz"
Abc.Xyz@domain.com

But none of them are populating the circulations field - they stay blank.

Any solutions for this?

Same query has been raised on MSDN with no solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your recipient column is a person/group field correct?  Also what triggers the workflow?  Does the recipient have to fill something out to start this process?  If so, you can just ust the Created By field to populate the recipient field in your other list.

I've used domain\userid and email address successfully in the past to set people/group fields via workflow.

Comment: Recipient column by default is "Send To" and is not editable.